# JSONArray stays empty till a menu item is clicked

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

App description: This app shows a list of popular/top-rated movies in the main activity as movie posters taken from themoviedb.org. I can favorite/unfavorite a movie, and favorites' movie ids, titles, and poster paths are saved in a database.
I can click on FAVORITES option to show my favorite movies.

Problem:

When I unfavorite a movie either by clicking on its poster in the favorites list or the popular or top-rated list, the favorites view does show the correct posters, but I get the movie details of the last movie unfavorited on tapping the poster that is now in that place. Clicking for the second time, things are okay or I click the favorite option again.
Logs show my JSONArray favoriteJsonArray stays empty till I do the click a second time on the poster or click on favortie option.

Code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.popularmovies.Database.Contract;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.utilities.NetworkUtils;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String BASE_POSTER_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
    private static String OPTION = "OPTION";

    TextView mNoFavorites;
    JSONArray favoriteJsonArray = new JSONArray();

    int optionChosen;

    private ProgressBar mProgessBar;
    private TextView mErrorMessage;
    private Button mRetry;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private URL url;
    private ArrayList<String> posterList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        //mAdapter = new MainActivityAdapter(this, posterList, null);
        //mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mProgessBar = findViewById(R.id.progess_bar);
        mErrorMessage = findViewById(R.id.error_message);
        mRetry = findViewById(R.id.retry);
        mNoFavorites = findViewById(R.id.no_favorites_yet);
        favoriteJsonArray = new JSONArray();
        tryToConnect(new View(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.preferences, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        try {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.top_rated) {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mNoFavorites.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                url = NetworkUtils.buildUrl("top_rated");
                if (url != null) {
                    mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mRetry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    new FetchMovies().execute(url, null, null);
                }
                optionChosen = 1;
            }
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.most_popular) {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mNoFavorites.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                url = NetworkUtils.buildUrl("most_popular");
                if (url != null) {
                    mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mRetry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    new FetchMovies().execute(url, null, null);
                }
                optionChosen = 2;
            }
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.favorites) {
                optionFavorites();
                optionChosen = 3;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (optionChosen == 3)
            optionFavorites();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the user's current game state
        savedInstanceState.putInt(OPTION, optionChosen);


        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore state members from saved instance
        optionChosen = savedInstanceState.getInt(OPTION);

    }

    private void optionFavorites() {
        try {
            String[] projection = {"movie_id", "favorite_poster_path"};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );
            ArrayList<String> posterPathArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<URL> urlArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String posterPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.FAVORITE_POSTER_PATH));
                    posterPathArrayList.add(BASE_POSTER_URL + posterPath);
                    int movieId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("movie_id"));
                    URL favoriteURL = NetworkUtils.buildUrl("favorites", movieId);
                    urlArrayList.add(favoriteURL);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                new FetchFavorites().execute(urlArrayList);
                mAdapter = new MainActivityAdapter(MainActivity.this, posterPathArrayList, favoriteJsonArray);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } else {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mNoFavorites.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void noConnection() {
        mErrorMessage.setText(R.string.no_connection);
        mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRetry.setText(R.string.retry);
        mRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void tryToConnect(View v) {
        try {
            url = NetworkUtils.buildUrl("most_popular");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (url != null) {
            mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRetry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new FetchMovies().execute(url, null, null);
        }
    }


    private class FetchMovies extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgessBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
            URL searchUrl = params[0];
            String searchResults = null;
            try {
                searchResults = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return searchResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String searchResults) {
            mProgessBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            try {
                posterList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (searchResults != null && !searchResults.equals("")) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(searchResults);
                    JSONArray pageOne = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    int length = pageOne.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        JSONObject result = pageOne.getJSONObject(i);
                        String posterPath = BASE_POSTER_URL + result.getString("poster_path");
                        posterList.add(posterPath);
                    }
                    mAdapter = new MainActivityAdapter(MainActivity.this, posterList, pageOne);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                } else noConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class FetchFavorites extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<URL>, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
     /*   @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgessBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }*/

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<URL>... params) {
            ArrayList<URL> arrayList = params[0];
            ArrayList<String> searchResultsList = new ArrayList<>();
            String searchResults;
            URL searchUrl;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                searchUrl = arrayList.get(i);
                try {
                    searchResults = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl);
                    searchResultsList.add(searchResults);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return searchResultsList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> searchResultsList) {
            mProgessBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            favoriteJsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < searchResultsList.size(); i++) {
                    String searchResults = searchResultsList.get(i);
                    if (searchResults != null && !searchResults.equals(""))
                        favoriteJsonArray.put(new JSONObject(searchResults));
                    else
                        noConnection();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivityAdapter:

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivityAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<String> mPosterList;
    private final Context mContext;
    private JSONArray mJsonArray;

    // Provide a suitable mConstructorInvoked (depends on the kind of dataset)
    MainActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> posterList, JSONArray jsonArray) {
        this.mPosterList = posterList;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mJsonArray = jsonArray;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MainActivityAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,
                                                             int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        ImageView v = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_image_view, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mPosterList.get(position)).into(holder.mImageView);
        holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    jsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetails.class);
                    Intent reviewIntent = new Intent(mContext, MovieReviews.class);
                    intent.putExtra("title", jsonObject.getString("title"));
                    intent.putExtra("poster", jsonObject.getString("poster_path"));
                    intent.putExtra("overview", jsonObject.getString("overview"));
                    intent.putExtra("userRating", jsonObject.getString("vote_average"));
                    intent.putExtra("releaseDate", jsonObject.getString("release_date"));
                    intent.putExtra("movieId", jsonObject.getInt("id"));

                    reviewIntent.putExtra("movieId", jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPosterList.size();
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case

        final ImageView mImageView;

        ViewHolder(ImageView v) {
            super(v);
            mImageView = v;
        }
    }
}
```

MovieDetails:

```
package com.example.android.popularmovies;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.example.android.popularmovies.Database.Contract;
import com.example.android.popularmovies.utilities.NetworkUtils;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MovieDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String title;
    private long position;
    private ToggleButton favoriteButton;
    private ProgressBar mProgessBar;
    private MovieTrailersAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> mTrailerList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int mMovieId;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private TextView mErrorMessage;
    private Button mRetry;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.read_reviews, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.read_reviews) {
            Intent reviewIntent = new Intent(this, MovieReviews.class);
            reviewIntent.putExtra("movieId", mMovieId);
            startActivity(reviewIntent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void noConnection() {
        mErrorMessage.setText(R.string.no_connection);
        mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRetry.setText(R.string.retry);
        mRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void tryToConnect(View v) {
        try {
            URL movieTrailerUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl("trailers", mMovieId);
            mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRetry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new FetchMovieTrailers().execute(
                    movieTrailerUrl,
                    null,
                    null);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);
        try {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.trailer_recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MovieTrailersAdapter(this, mTrailerList);
        mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(),
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        mProgessBar = findViewById(R.id.progess_bar_trailers);
        mErrorMessage = findViewById(R.id.error_message_trailers);
        mRetry = findViewById(R.id.retry_trailers);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mMovieId = intent.getIntExtra("movieId", 0);
        title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        final String poster = intent.getStringExtra("poster");
        String overview = intent.getStringExtra("overview");
        String userRating = intent.getStringExtra("userRating");
        String releaseDate = intent.getStringExtra("releaseDate");
        TextView titleTV = findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTV.setText(title);
        TextView overviewTV = findViewById(R.id.overview);
        overviewTV.setText(overview);
        TextView userRatingTV = findViewById(R.id.user_rating);
        String rating = userRating + getString(R.string.out_of_ten);
        userRatingTV.setText(rating);
        TextView releaseDateTV = findViewById(R.id.release_date);
        releaseDateTV.setText(releaseDate.substring(0, 4)); //Returns year of release
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.poster);
        String POSTER_PATH = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
        Picasso.with(this).load(POSTER_PATH + poster).into(imageView);
        tryToConnect(new View(this));
        favoriteButton = findViewById(R.id.mark_as_favorite);
        boolean isFavorite = isMovieFavorite();
        if (!isFavorite)
            favoriteButton.setChecked(false);
        else
            favoriteButton.setChecked(true);


        favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isFavorite = isMovieFavorite();
                        if (!isFavorite) {

                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                            contentValues.put(Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
                            contentValues.put(Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.MOVIE_ID, mMovieId);
                            contentValues.put(Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.FAVORITE_POSTER_PATH, poster);

                            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

                            if (uri != null)
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            favoriteButton.setChecked(true);

                        } else {

                            Uri uri = Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.CONTENT_URI;
                            uri = uri.buildUpon().appendPath(String.valueOf(position)).build();

                            int result = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                            if (result > 0)
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " " + "removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " " + "not a favorite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            favoriteButton.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    private boolean isMovieFavorite() {

        String[] projection = {"_id", "movie_id"};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            do {
                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.FavoriteMovieDatabase.MOVIE_ID)) == mMovieId) {
                    position = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    return true;
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    private class FetchMovieTrailers extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgessBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
            URL searchUrl = params[0];
            String searchResults = null;
            try {
                searchResults = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(searchUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return searchResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String searchResults) {
            mProgessBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            try {
                mTrailerList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (searchResults != null && !searchResults.equals("")) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(searchResults);
                    JSONArray pageOne = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    int length = pageOne.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        JSONObject result = pageOne.getJSONObject(i);
                        String movieTrailerKey = result.getString("key");
                        mTrailerList.add(movieTrailerKey);
                    }
                    mAdapter = new MovieTrailersAdapter(MovieDetails.this, mTrailerList);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                } else
                    noConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Further explanation of the problem:
When I click on a movie poster in the favorites movie collection (stored in a database), and I click on remove from favorites, then go back to favorites collection, the poster of that movie does not show as expected. However, clicking on a movie poster that is in the previous poster's place still shows movie details for the previous movie.

Comment: You might have posted too much code...

Comment: explain breifly not getting your problem